# Yii - jQuery not working after renderPartial

Tags: jquery, yii, renderpartial

I know this question has been asked numerous number of times, both here and in the Yii site, but I am not getting the solution even after going through each solution. I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong. So if you are still reading this - here goes nothing,

I have a page that has a CheckBoxList widget being loaded. It has a change() jQuery function call which refreshes a CGridView which works perfectly well. I also have a span related to each of the items in the checkBoxList which have a click event.

This click event, in turn calls a controller which "partially renders" a view -

```
Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;


$this->widget('ext.xxx.EModelWidget', array(
'name' => $widget_name,
'manufacturer_id' => $manufacturer_id,
    )
);
```

And the corresponding widget code prints a CheckBoxList after fetching $data from the db.

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList($this->name, array(), $data, array(
        'class' => 'modelFilter',
        'separator' => '',
        'template' => '<div>{input} {label}</div>',
        'id' => 'dummyID',
    ));
```

As you can see, I have put the class name for each element that will be rendered as a checkbox to be **modelFilter**

Now I have a script in the main view file to just display an alert box when the checkBox of class modelFilter is clicked.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('model-selected', "
$('input.modelFilter').change(function(){
  alert('Hellpo!');
  });
");
```

But unfortunately, this never happens.

The two common solutions which I have read in all the forums is

a) **Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;** which you can see that I have duly followed.

b) **$result and $processOutput parameters of the renderPartial to be false and true respectively.**, which is also something that I have followed.

So my question is what should I do to just get the change function on a content that is loaded via Ajax working, in Yii!!

Comment: As far as I understand it ... the click event also fires an AJAX request? If this is the case could you check if there's a jQuery JavaScript include in the response? If so, this may reinitialize your jQuery and mess up your JavaScript logic, although you should be able to disable this by setting processOutput to 'false'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are calling `$('input.modelFilter').change()` before you load the list of checkboxes. Used like that the event handler will not be bound to any elements inserted after the call.

You have to use delegated events instead of directly bound events. Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (search for "Direct and delegated events")

```
$("body_or_input_container").on("change", "input.modelFilter", function(e){
    //callback
});
```

Comment: Looks promising. Let me check on this and get back to you! Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, after I performed an Ajax call which returned a partial rendered HTML with javascript inside (auto generated by Yii's CActiveForm) everything was broken because no jQuery plugin has been recognized anymore.

After a long research I found that the partial is sending the jQuery lib again and it reinitializes itself by "forgetting" everything what has been initialized before (especially other plugins, in my case the UI dialog).
The only fix was to tell Yii to not include the jQuery.js itself in the partial but let include other JS files.

So put this at the beginning of the partial.

```
Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
```

Note that you must configure to load the jQuery once at the page load.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the same issue. Was very difficult to debug. Yii is a strange framework.

Answer (score 0):

OK, on solution that I found, be it accidentally, was to include the jQuery script for the partially rendered file, in the partially rendered file itself.

I want to know if this style is correct, though.

Comment: But I dont find this to be a very good solution. I am not able to even update the gridView which is on the main view page!! :(

Answer (score 0):

In case of eye renderPartial it destroys the existing object of javascript

e.g

I have a form with parsley j's validation it works perfectly when we use render () but doesn't recognize the parsley object. so we need to reinitialize the object again in my case it was

$("#form").parsley();